# Project migration to new directory - keeping Git history

Tags: java, git, jakarta-ee, github

I have recent migrated a Java EE project from 5 to 6, as this required quite a big overhaul I created a new EE6 skeleton project and copied most of the code across manually. I now have my working EE6 project (and an obsolete EE 5 project).

I would like to keep my Git history, is there are recommended way to move the .git directory into the new project so that all the updates are picked up as a new commit? Or can I just copy the .git folder over? Or do I have to start from scratch and lose the history?

Thanks, I am sure this must have been asked before but I have been unable to find any questions that relate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the `.git` folder in the new project, and check that a git status does pick up all your changes (`git add -A .` after that, in order to add any new, modified or deleted files).

A more clean solution  would be to :

- initialize an empty git repo in your project (`git init .`)
- add as a remote a path to your previous project (`git remote add origin /path/to/previous/project`, where a `.git/` folder reside.

Then, using [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) and [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

```
git fetch
git branch master origin/master
git reset --soft master
```